# URL amigável automática em PHP

Tags: php, htaccess, url, url-amigável

Estou querendo desenvolver um site tipo o `migre.me`, ele não usa método `GET` visível, e a URL dele fica desta forma:

```
http://migre.me/upR3N
```

Eu quero fazer um sistema para salvar o URL no MySQL, e criar uma URL deste tipo, sem usar método `GET`.

Não quero deixar assim:

```
http://meusite.me/?url=upR3N
```

Como faço para deixar como o primeiro *link*?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140220075845/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seu `.htaccess` ficaria assim:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
</IfModule>
```

Com isso defino que ocultarei o `index.php` do link, e o `$_GET['url']` valerá todo o restante do meu link após o `index`.

Após isso basta manipular essa variável para pegar os parâmetros do link, no seu caso, como me parece que sempre haverá somente um parâmetro então fica mais simples, só pegar o `$_GET['url]` em qualquer lugar e pronto. Um exemplo seria o `index.php` assim:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['url']))
    echo "<h1>Param: " . $_GET['url'] . "</h1>";
else
    echo "<h1>Param Undefined!</h1>";
```

Quando se tem mais de um parâmetro, deve-se usar um controlador para resgatar os parâmetros, vou exemplificar com um código de um micro framework que desenvolvi nessas férias. Parte do controlador de parâmetros é assim:

```
// pego os parametros
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : '';
// apago a variavel do get
unset($_GET['url']);
// se tiver algum parametro
if(!empty($url))
{
    // separo os parametros em um array, exemplo meusite.com/categoria/1
    // ficaria [0] = 'categoria', [1] = '1'
    $params = explode('/', $url);

    // arqui enta o MVC, pego meu controller
    $_GET['controller'] = isset($params[0]) ? $params[0] : '';

    // aqui entra parte do meu framework, verificando se há um sinônimo para esse controller
    $alias = Alias::check($_GET['controller']);

    // se achou um sinônimo
    if($alias != false)
    {
        // pega o controller e o metodo daquele sinonimo encontrado
        $_GET['controller'] = explode('/', $alias)[0];
        $_GET['method'] =  explode('/', $alias)[1];
    }
    // se nao achou um sinonimo do link
    else
    {
        // pega o metodo da URL e deleta o mesmo do array
        $_GET['method'] = isset($params[1]) ? $params[1] : '';
        unset($params[1]);
    }

    // deleta o controller do array
    unset($params[0]);

    // pega os demais parametros
    $get = array();
    foreach ($params as $value)
        array_push($get, $value);
    $_GET['params'] = $get;
}
```

Acho que mostrando um exemplo mais complexo dá para entender mais sobre o assunto.

**Ps.:** para fazer o uso de URL amigáveis no Apache, é necessário habilitar o módulo `rewrite`, algumas hospedagem já o deixa habilitado, outras não, nesses casos é necessário entrar em contato com o suporte pedir o serviço. Caso esteja no `localhost`, ele pode ser habilitado no *WAMP* da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou manualmente no **httpd.conf**:

Descomente ou inclua: (linha 109, normalmente)

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Ficando assim:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Substitua todos:

```
AllowOverride None
```

por:

```
AllowOverride All
```

e assim deve funcionar..

Comment: Usei exatamente o codigo do htaccess que vc mandou mas nao funcionou por algum motivo desconhecido. http://towerscraft.com.br/towersgo/?url=12 - http://towerscraft.com.br/towersgo/12 - essa nao funciona - arquivos: http://prntscr.com/bw7hg8

Comment: Vou dar uma verificada. O código no index é apenas um `echo` em `$_GET['url']`?

Comment: Sim, exatamente isso

Comment: Vou dar uma editada na resposta, com um exemplo, mas é basicamente o mesmo, testei aqui e funcionou. Com certeza a sua hospedagem por padrão deixa o `mod_rewrite` do Apache desabilitado, então você deve entrar em contato com o suporte e verificar se eles dão suporte, se sim, pedir a habilitação do mesmo. Se quiser testar no *localhost* vou colocar na resposta como habilitar ele no *WAMP*.

Comment: Eu tenho uma dedicado na OVH, eu instalei eu mesmo o apache, sabe como posso habilitar isso da httpd.conf ?

Comment: Vou adicionar na resposta.

Comment: Fiz td isso, e reiniciei o apache e ainda nao resolveu

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42888/discussion-between-lvcs-and-gamestdai).